# Problem while trying to create a new virtual machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, virtualbox

I am trying to install a virtual machine in my computer, I have windows 10. I installed virtual box and I created a new machine, when I try to start the machine, it says : unpacking failed: write error.

`unpacking failed: write error failed to execute/init kernel panick: not suncing: no working init found. Try passing init=option to kernel`

Can you help me please, I really don't understand the problem, it was supposed to just open the machine. I can provide any other important information, just ask for it.

Comment: Did you try to install from a regular ISO?   That should open the VBOX installation settings.

Comment: What setting did you give for the new VM machine that you created (RAM, storage, etc.?) and which OS are you trying to install?